# Iterator does not move to the next list item

Tags: flutter

I would like to iterate over a list by click so my code is the following:

```
List<Member> matchMemberList = [];
iterator = matchMemberList.iterator;

SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
               Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   const SizedBox(height: 10),
                   Row(
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                     children: <Widget>[
                       Container(
                         child: CircleAvatar(
                           backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                           radius: 40,
                           child: IconButton(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                             icon: const Icon(Icons.clear, size: 40,color: Colors.red),
                             color: Colors.white,
                             onPressed: () async {
                                 iterator.moveNext();
                                 await _db.setLikesData(
                                     currentUserId: GlobalData.currentUser?.uid,
                                     selectedUserId: matchMemberList[index].uid,
                                     likeValue: false
                                 );
                              
                             },
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),
                       Container(
                         child: CircleAvatar(
                           backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                           radius: 40,
                           child: IconButton(
                             padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                             icon: const Icon(Icons.check, size: 40,color: Colors.lightGreen,),
                             color: Colors.white,
                             onPressed: () async {
                                 iterator.moveNext();
                                 await _db.setLikesData(
                                     currentUserId: GlobalData.currentUser?.uid,
                                     selectedUserId: matchMemberList[index].uid,
                                     likeValue: true
                                 );
                               
                             },
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),
                     ],
                   ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10)
                 ],
               )
              ],
            ),
          )
```

When a button is clicked the data are written to the database but the iterator it not moving to the next element in the list.

Let me know if you need more information!
Thanks

Comment: how do you know if you dont call [Iterator.current](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterator/current.html) anywhere in your code?

Comment: because i did't knew that its necessary, where do i have to place this method?Yesterday it works without the current method

Comment: what's the point of the iterator if you don't do anything with it? And you reference some `index` that I don't see declared or changed anywhere

Comment: after `iterator.moveNext()` for example - you can see how it works if you`print(iterator.current)`

Comment: I would like to ask the question new with more example code, for some reason now it works without current.